# Rails/Heroku Subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, networking, heroku, dns

I'm currently trying to setup masking for one of my rails app subdomains.

Hypothetically, my main app website is called www.cats.com

I've got a subdomain on this main application called www.care.cats.com

I've got another domain managed by GoDaddy called www.catscare.com

Currently, I have it setup such that going to www.catscare.com goes to www.care.cats.com as it should. However, whenever I try to add a slug at the end of that link for example (www.catscare.com/blah), my rails application gives me a 404, whereas if I go to www.care.cats.com/blah, it gives me the correct page. I think this has something to do with my subdomain constraints in my routes.rb file.

```
scope "/:slug", module: :claims_portal, as: :claims_portal, constraints: ClaimsPortalConstraint.new do
```

My actual constraints file is here:

```
class ClaimsPortalConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    in_claims_subdomain?(request) && merchant_exists?(request)
  end

  private

  def in_claims_subdomain?(request)
    request.subdomain =~ /^(claims|claims-sandbox|claims-staging|claims-regression|care|care-sandbox|care-staging|care-regression)$/
  end

  def merchant_exists?(request)
    Company.find_by(slug: request.params[:slug]).present?
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you put in some `Rails.logger.debug` to see if `matches?` is returning true?

Comment: Would be kind of difficult as it is currently pointed to the production server. Any easy way to do this with ngrok?

Comment: with rails and heroku I just run `heroku run rails c` in the terminal

Comment: You might be able to change `/etc/hosts` to point the production domains to localhost. Be sure to remember to change it back afterwards :)